# Set Block Class Property from Custom Module Controller

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to access block class method from controller and set some value to block class property. The method is being accessed but when I try to print the property in .phtml file it is NULL.
Here is my code:
app/code/local/Amactech/Events/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

    class Amactech_Events_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
        public function indexAction(){

            $block=$this->getLayout()->createBlock('events/events');
            $block->setFeedback("wrwqerqwer fasdfasdf vxzcvzxcv");

            $this->loadLayout();
            return $this->renderLayout();
        }

    }
```

?>

app/code/local/Amactech/Events/Block/Event.php

```
<?php

  class Amactech_Events_Block_Events extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{

    public $_feedback;

    public function setFeedback($feedback){
      echo $feedback;
      $this->_feedback = $feedback;
    }

    public function getFeedback(){
      echo "get feedback"; /*This line is being printing which means I am getting in this method*/
      return $this->_feedback;
    }


  }

?>
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/events/events.phtml

```
<?php
    echo $this->getFeedback();
?>
```

So I am accessing block setFeedback() method and setting $_feedback value. I print something string inside setFeedback() and getFeedback() methods to check whether I am getting into these methods. The printing string is shown which means I am getting into the methods but when I assign some value to property and try to print the property is shows NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try magento session instead for setting up a value to block.

I think in the above case the value comes only while you call the controller, right ?

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFeedback($inputMessage); // In controller

Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFeedback($inputMessage); // In PHTML
```